# Passing calculation commands to cluster job

Tags: bash, escaping, lsf

**TL;DR**
Trying to pass a computation of the form `$(($LSB_JOBINDEX-1))` to a cluster call, but getting an error

```
$((2-1)): syntax error: operand expected (error token is "$((2-1))")
```

How do I escape correctly or what alternative command to use so that this works?

**Detailed:**

For automatations in my workflow I am currently trying to write a script that automatically issues `bsub` commands in a predefined order.

Some of these commands are array jobs that are supposed to work on a file each. 
If done without the cluster calls, it would look something like this:

```
samplearray=(sample0.fasta sample1.fasta) #array of input files
for s in samplearray
    echo $s #some command on $s
done
```

for the cluster call I want to use an array job, the command for this looks like this:

```
bsub -J test[1-2] 'samplearray=(sample0.fastq sample1.fastq)' echo '${samplearray[$(($LSB_JOBINDEX-1))]}'
```

which launches two jobs with `LSB_JOBINDEX`set to 1 or 2 respectively, which is why I need to subtract 1 for correct indexing of the array.

The problem now is in the `$((...))` part, because what is being executed on the node is `${samplearray[$\(\($LSB_JOBINDEX-1\)\)]}` which does not trigger the computation but instead throws an error:

```
$((2-1)): syntax error: operand expected (error token is "$((2-1))")
```

What am I doing wrong here? I have tried other ways of escaping and quoting, but this was the closest I got to the correct solution

Comment: I don't know how bsub ends up executing such commands, but you could just remove the `$((` and `))` part since array indices are already an arithmetic context

Comment: thx @thatotherguy I actually did not know this, I will try that tomorrow, but I am positive that it might solve the problem